# Multiple view controllers on screen at once?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to wrap my head around controllers in Cocoa Touch. The main problem is that I would like to have more than one controller “on screen” at once – I want to have a large view (with controller A) composed of smaller views controlled by their own controllers (say B). I’d like to have it this way because the division makes the code much cleaner. What’s bad is that the additional controllers (of type B) are not “first-class citizens” on the screen, for example they do not receive the autorotation queries and notifications. (And cannot easily display modal controllers, they have to send the `presentModal…` message to their parent controller.)

What is the difference between the A and B controllers from Cocoa viewpoint? Does the system keep some kind of pointer to the “frontmost controller”, a privileged one to which it sends notifications and such stuff? Why don’t the other controllers receive them, even though their views are on the screen? Is having multiple controllers “on screen” considered a hack? Or is it supported and I am just missing some point? Thank you.

---

More about the problem I am trying to solve: I am writing a simple photo browser. Photos are displayed in full screen, user can swipe left or right to change photos. The A controller takes care of the scrolling part and the B controllers take care of each photo itself.

Isolating B seemed like a good idea, since the photos are loaded from network and there is a lot that can happen, like the network might be down et cetera. In the B controller the code is fairly simple, since B only works with one particular photo. If I moved the code to the A controller, things would get messy.

The only thing I don’t like about the current solution is that I have to manually work around B not being a “first-class” controller. I have to pass some calls manually through A to B and when B wants to display a modal dialog, it has to send the `presentModal…` to A. Which is ugly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is now a first-class support for this scenario since iOS 5, it’s called controller containment.

[swift controller containment](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-use-view-controller-containment)

[objc controller containment](https://www.objc.io/issues/1-view-controllers/containment-view-controller/).

Answer (score 12):

It's not closely related to the original question but important. Apple clearly states in View Controller Programming Guide that a view controller is responsible for controlling exactly one screen's content:

"Each custom view controller object you create is responsible for managing exactly one screen’s worth of content. The one-to-one correspondence between a view controller and a screen is a very important consideration in the design of your application. You should not use multiple custom view controllers to manage different portions of the same screen. Similarly, you should not use a single custom view controller object to manage multiple screens worth of content.

Note: If you want to divide a single screen into multiple areas and manage each one separately, use generic controller objects (custom objects descending from NSObject) instead of view controller objects to manage each subsection of the screen. Then use a single view controller object to manage the generic controller objects. The view controller coordinates the overall screen interactions but forwards messages as needed to the generic controller objects it manages."

However in iPad Programming Guide they also say that there may be container view controllers:

"A view controller is responsible for a single view. Most of the time, a view controller’s view is expected to fill the entire span of the application window. In some cases, though, a view controller may be embedded inside another view controller (known as a container view controller) and presented along with other content. Navigation and tab bar controllers are examples of container view controllers."

Up to my current knowledge I would not use sub-view controllers in a view controller but try to subclass NSObject and send messages to them from my main view controller.

Also check this thread:
[MGSplitViewController discussion](http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad/comment-page-1#comment-43696)

Comment: The problem is how to pass a message from the generic NSObject controller Object to the View Controller.  You'd need either delegates or NSNotifications which is a pain.

Comment: I would disagree that 1 screen = 1 uivc, also there is no documentation where apple states that.

Comment: @denis_lor https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerPGforiOSLegacy/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html

Answer (score 8):

First, and this is important, view *controllers* don't get "on screen" -- *views* do. Your "top level" controller can certainly pass along the kinds of messages you're describing to its "sub-view-controllers". In fact, this is how most apps work. Consider an app that has a tab bar, and where the views use navigation controllers. You actually have several view controllers "running" at the same time, each with its own view on screen at once -- your "root" view controller will be an instance (or subclass) of UITabBarController, which then has several nested UINavigationControllers, each which will display nested view controllers (like an instance or a subclass of UITableViewController).

You might want to read up a bit on how [responder chains](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html) work. Consider a touch event. It will be generated for the view closest to the top of the stack, that can receive events, which is also underneath the tap. If that view can't handle it, it gets passed up the view hierarchy food chain until something deals with it (and then eats it).

As to the specifics of your question, on the whole, I'm not sure exactly what the strategy you describe is really doing to benefit you in terms of complexity. It depends on how exactly you're implementing things, but having separate view controllers for each little subview may require more bookkeeping code than just having one view controller that knows about all its sub-view components.

Comment: Good answer, thank you. I know that views come on screen, not controllers, that’s why I kept writing “on screen” in quotes, meaning “having its view on screen.” I’ll write more about the situation in the question.

Answer (score 6):

This is a pretty old question, but since I guess there are people who might face the same problem today I'd like to share my solution.
I was writing this application that had this one screen with a lot of information, pagination, controls etc. Since according to Apple's MVC [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/) on the role of ViewControllers, you should not implement the logic in view itself, or access the data model directly from it, I had to choose between having a Massive ViewController with a few thousand lines of code which was both hard to maintain and debug(even with unit tests) or find a new way.

My solution was to use `UIContainerView` like below:
[image]

this way, you can implement each part's logic in it's own ViewController, and the parent view controller takes care of constraints and sizing of the views.

**Note: This answer is just a guide to show the way, you can find a good and detailed explanation on how it works and how to implement it [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH11-SW1)**

Answer (score 5):

Actually you can make it work earlier than iOS 5, since most of us are targeting 4.x and 5.x at the same time. I've created a solution that works in both, and it works great, few apps in appstore use it :) Read [my article about this](http://www.merowing.info/2012/02/uiviewcontroller-containment/) or just [download and use a simple class](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/SFContainerViewController) that I've created for this purpose.

Comment: It's considered bad practice by Apple to do this before ios5 (i.e. before we had Apple' provided containment). Apple engineers told me so in person.

Comment: I had been using this solution for over a year, and I never had any problems with it. The problem is most of implementations I've seen didn't take care of properly handling memory and all important methods, and mine DOES handle it properly. As much as I Love apple view controller containment should be introduced with the release of iPad, as this is the most common scenario for multiple view controllers. Again this is solution that is approved in many apps in appstore. This solutions allows to reuse iPhone view controllers without any fuss or headache.