# Using InfiniTabBar ( a UIScrollView subclass ) and pushing UINavigationControllers into it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

This question is about the usage of the InfiniTabBar and a problem with using "Sub View Controllers"

Here is the set up:

I have a RootViewController that adds an instance of InfiniTabBar ( https://github.com/iosdeveloper/InfiniTabBar ) as a subview. 
When the user clicks on one of the UITabBarItems you would want to load a ViewController associated with that UITabBarItem.

However, after looking at this Stack Overflow question ( [Multiple view controllers on screen at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423858/multiple-view-controllers-on-screen-at-once) ) about using multiple View Controllers on one screen, it made me question how to use the InfiniTabBar.

With that information, it seems to me that for every button on the InfiniTabBar that is clicked, a new View Controller would have to be loaded. That View Controller would then have to create and have its own instance of the InfiniTabBar added as a subview. Otherwise, you would have a scenario where there would be more than one View Controller controlling a screen.

My question is : To use the InfiniTabBar properly, would I have to violate this rule?
"Each custom view controller object you create is responsible for managing exactly one screen’s worth of content. ... "

**EDIT:**

A rephrasing of the question: 
If InfiniTabBar is a subclass of UIScrollView, how does one properly use it in place of a UITabBarController? 
The later can be a rootViewController as it is a subclass of UIViewController, while the former cannot.